# Is it possible to add text to every image path on hover using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm wondering, I have alot of image on my website that behave depending on the class. I was wondering if it would be possible using CSS to do this for example.

```
   .willReactOnHover.class1{ background: url('../images/image1.png');}
   .willReactOnHover.class2{ background: url('../images/image2.png');}
```

And then, on hover

```
   .willReactOnHover:hover{
        background: /*Here, .class1 would be .image1-hover.png AND
        .class2 would be .image2-hover.png */           
    }
```

I don't know if it's possible to just had a suffix -hover to all the existing path even if different... I know in javascript I could but I'd love a pure CSS solution else I'll have to create the hover event for every class but since it's the same task for each class I don't know if there's a way it'd be optimal. Or maybe is there a CSS selector that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: css isn't programmable. you can certainly set a different url on a `:hover()`, but there's no string functionality to do `url('../images/' + css_class_of_current_object)` or whatever.

Comment: Yeah it's what I tought also, I don't think there is anyways to achieve this but sometimes with css3 selectors I tought maybe there would be a way

Comment: it'd be pretty easy to do with javascript, of course.

Comment: Using SASS it would certainely be possible but the problem is I don't think that the outputted CSS would be very sexy... having an hover class for each maybe I should do it straith with javascript?

Comment: This seems like a very odd way to achieve what you are attempting. If you have a page with a lot of images why would you double the number of images in order to include text on hover? Couldn't you just add in an absolute positioned div with the text you want to overlay and only show it on hover? You didn't say whether or not you have access to the markup, but if you do this would be a much better solution.

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explained it well enough, I want to add text to my path to get the image on hover, I don't want to add text to my html in an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before CSS-3 people often used `background-position` along with a image-sprite so you could use the old-horse background-position , like so :

```
.willReactOnHover.class1{ background: url('../images/image1.png');}
   .willReactOnHover.class2{ background: url('../images/image2.png');} 

.willReactOnHover:hover{
        background-position:-10px;          
    }
```

Comment: You are right maybe I should use sprite, but I'd have to make sure every icons are the same size. Still, I think it's the best option

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this seems to be impossible with pure CSS at the moment. If you use a prepocessor, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#), you could use a [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) to accomplish what you want very easily:

**Example CSS**

```
@url: "../images/image";
@ext: ".png";
@hover: "_hover";

.generate-images(5);

.generate-images(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .class@{i} {
    background-image: url("@{url}@{i}@{ext}");
  }
  .class@{i}:hover {
    background-image: url("@{url}@{i}@{hover}@{ext}");
  }
  .generate-images(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPymYN)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could define a CSS rule for each class that you need.

Perhaps the following may be helpful.

```css
.willhover.class1 {
  color: blue;
}
.willhover.class2 {
  color: green;
}
.willhover.class1:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.willhover.class2:hover {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="willhover class1">Class 1</div>
<div class="willhover class2">Class 2</div>
```

However, you still need to create specific two types of CSS rules, one for pointing to the non-hover image and the other pointing to the hover image.